# Unexpected response code 429 when using Volley in Android?

Tags: java, android, http, android-volley

I'm able to fetch JSON information from a URL for a few minutes, however eventually it'll give me "Unexpected response code 429". The link is from Steam, I'm wondering if this is a problem with Volley or Steam? Here is my current implementation as it could be possible I'm missing something from my code.

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

            // Request a string response from the provided URL.
            JsonObjectRequest stringRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, retrievalURL, null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try {
                               int indexOfWear = listOfWears.indexOf(wear);
                                Map<String, String> itemInList = listWearsAndPrices.get(indexOfWear);
                                if (response.getBoolean("success")) {
                                    itemInList.put("Price", response.getString("lowest_price"));
                                } else {
                                    // If price is not possible
                                    itemInList.put("Price", "Item Unavailable");
                                    Log.e("tag", "Item unavailable unreached");
                                }
                                // Update view
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }


                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    /**
                     * TODO
                     * CHECK FOR INTERNET CONNECTION
                     */
                    int indexOfWear = listOfWears.indexOf(wear);
                    Map<String, String> itemInList = listWearsAndPrices.get(indexOfWear);
                    itemInList.put("Price", "Item Unavailable");
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
            queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: Did you check the internet connection before hitting the service ?

Answer (score 1):

**429 response code means**

```
Too Many Requests

The user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time ("rate limiting").
```

Probably api you are trying to hit is limited to number of hits you can make in day or certain amount of time.